# Read/Write BigTIFF using BioFormat

Tags: java, imagej, fiji

I need to I/O large images in `TIFF` format, so I need to use the `BigTIFF` format. I tried to use `BioFormats` (`bioformats_package.jar`) last version to read an image, using:

```
ImagePlus[] images = images = BF.openImagePlus(io) ;
```

Then, I wanted to access the Processor `images[0].getProcessor()` to modify/access the pixel values, but the result appears to not be any of the classical ImageJ processor: `ByteProcessor`, `ColorProcessor`, `FloatProcessor`, and `ShortProcessor`. I tested ALL of them using `instanceof`.

Any idea what type of `Processor` it could be?

Or how I would access the pixel values?

[EDIT] I still don't know what type of ImageProcessor the result is, but I found out that the saved pixels are encoded using Float, so 32 bits.

This is not ideal as I saved an image using Integer encoding, so there is a loss of precision when values are bigger than 20 millions.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDocs on [ImagePlus](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ij/ImagePlus.html), `getProcessor()` returns an [ImageProcessor](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ij/process/ImageProcessor.html) on which you can perform a `convertToByteProcessor()` to get a `ByteProcessor`, you have other converters on `ImageProcessor` for other subclasses.

Comment: Agreed. This `ImageProcessor` is supposed to be an instance of one of the four classes I listed, but it's not.

Comment: Please post more code, then, I fail to understand what the problem is ... you actually have to do `images[0].getProcessor().convertToByteProcessor()` to get a `ByteProcessor` but I guess you already know that and so I do not understand your problem. You asked what type of Processor, I claim `ImageProcessor` that you have to convert to your preferred processor. My understanding is you want `ByteProcessor.getPixels()`

Comment: You do `convertToByteProcessor`if your `ImageProcessor` is indeed a ByteProcessor`, but it can also be another type of processor. That's what I'm saying, when reading a `BigTIFF`, the `ImageProcessor` has an encoding that is different and I don't know which one.